# WAL internals underhood arrangement in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I wanted to understand how the WAL file internally looks  -like is the below sequence one is correct.

Transaction  required->WAL logfile->WAL records->WAL segments ( each segements divided of 16MB size say ex)-> each segments have Pages(8KB)

Also I would like to know that can some one give Me internal WAL file- how it looks in an easy way and correct Me If Iam wrong..as Iam new to learn here so.

Answer (score 0):

WAL is split in *segments* (= files).

Each WAL segment contains WAL records. There are no blocks; WAL is written sequentially.

Comment: You Mean like   WAL Logfile->WAL segments(16MB-ex)->Mutiliple WAL records(say muiltiple of 8KBs)->each WAL log record will have header and changes data informations?.  Iam still confusion on this..

Comment: What would be the correct sequence if I need to tel?

Comment: There is no "WAL logfile". WAL records are *not* multiples of 8kB. FOr the details of how WAL records look, you'll have to read the code.

Answer (score 0):

Wal files are present in /PGData/pg_wal/ directory.If your interested to see the contents of wal file use pg_waldump utility.

For Example:-
/bin/pg_waldump -p <path_to_pg_wal_directory> 000000010000000000000042

Here
000000010000000000000042 is the name of WAL segment you want to explore.

EDIT:-
Each WAL segment(default 16 MB size) is divided into pages which is of 8kb(default) size,each page will have WAL records.

Each WAL record will basically have three things.

1.Type of record

2.Transaction id

3.LSN associated with it.

Comment: Thanks Manjunath,but I needed correct sequence.. here..to understand.. further I can explore in My machine so.